# Validate get when submitting with flask wtforms

Tags: flask, get, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form with validations, like `required()` or `NumberRange`.

This is a search functionality, so I am using get method. The problem is that I can't use `form.validate_on_submit()` with get. With `post` everything work as expected, but with `get` the form ignore the validations, basically never validate on submit.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
class DocSearch(Form):
    client_number = IntegerField(lazy_gettext(u'Client number'), [Required()])
    submit = SubmitField(lazy_gettext(u'Find'))
```

---

```
<form method="get" class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group ">
        {{ render_field(form.client_number) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group ">
        {{ render_field(form.submit) }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate_on_submit` is a convenience function that calls two other methods. The first, `is_submitted`, checks for POST and PUT requests. The second, [`validate`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.validate), does the actual validation. That's the one you need.

```
if form.validate():
    # do stuff here
```